# PHPMailer and attachement of a php generated png

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm struggling with sending a png file generated by a php code through PHPMailer.

So the button.php looks like this:

```
    header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['mail'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("button.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, 400, 55, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

and i'm trying to send it with this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment("button.php?mail=somemail", "filename.png", 'base64', 'image/png');
```

I receive the mail, but attachment file is broken. Experimented with file_get_contents(), but got nothing.

Thanks in advance for all Your help!

Comment: the first argument is the file string, not a file name

Comment: So i should use file_get_contents() ? Could You tell me how to do it. If i use it like this: `$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents('button.php?mail=somemail'), "filename.png", 'base64', 'image/png');` i get: no such file

Comment: Step 1: Learn the difference between file system paths, and URLs. `button.php?mail=somemail` would refer to a file with that actual, literal name. There are no GET parameters in the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment("button.php?mail=somemail", "filename.png", 'base64', 'image/png');
```

attaches the literal string `button.php?mail=somemail` as a PNG file, which it obviously isn't.

PHPMailer deliberately avoids acting as an HTTP client - that's up to you - so you should do something like:

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/button.php?mail=somemail');
if (false !== $imagedata) {
    $mail->addStringAttachment($imagedata, 'filename.png');
}
```

This allows you to know whether the request has succeeded before trying to attach the result, much better than doing it inline.

Note you don't need the encoding or mime type options in this case - they are set automatically.

Comment: Instead of making an HTTP request, they should probably just take the code from their button.php file, and use it directly - minus the header, and plus output buffering to capture the output of `imagepng`

Comment: Agreed, though that was the question asked.

Comment: @Synchro works great! Thank You. Misorude also thanks for advice - i also thought about making a "raw" output, but didn't know how to "output buffering to capture the output of imagepng" as You call it :)